# SQL Integration Services Web Service Task Problem

Tags: web-services, ssis

I am currently trying to use a web service I developed within an Integration Services package. When I try to configure the web service task I keep getting an error message. I configured the HTTP connection, and successfully downloaded the WSDL file which overrides my local copy. After that, on the input tab, I try to select the only service available "MyService" and then get the following error message:

---

Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'anyType'  Key being added: 'anyType'

---

Anyone knows what this means?

Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="MyService" targetNamespace="http://www.MyDomain.de/webservices" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:tns="http://www.MyDomain.de/webservices" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.MyDomain.de/webservices/Imports">
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/MyDomainMyService/MyDomain.Billing.Infrastructure.Wcf.MyService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://www.MyDomain.de/webservices" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/MyDomainMyService/MyDomain.Billing.Infrastructure.Wcf.MyService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="MyService_BookNewTransaction_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:BookNewTransaction" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="MyService_BookNewTransaction_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:BookNewTransactionResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="MyService">
    <wsdl:operation name="BookNewTransaction">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.MyDomain.de/webservices/MyService/BookNewTransaction" message="tns:MyService_BookNewTransaction_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.MyDomain.de/webservices/MyService/BookNewTransactionResponse" message="tns:MyService_BookNewTransaction_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyService" type="tns:MyService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="BookNewTransaction">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.MyDomain.de/webservices/MyService/BookNewTransaction" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="MyService">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_MyService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_MyService">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost/MyDomainMyService/MyDomain.Billing.Infrastructure.Wcf.MyService.svc" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a link describing my problem.

Check this: 
http://sjbdeveloper.blogspot.com/2007/03/calling-wcf-web-service-from-ssis-web.html

This should solve the problem:

http://sjbdeveloper.blogspot.com/2007/03/fixing-wcf-ssis-web-service-task.html